# Find method with specific argument using regular expression in VS2012

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2012

I want to find an (overloaded) method **X** where the argument in position **Y** has the value **Z**.

**Example:**

```
AddMailToQueue("a", "b", "c", 2);
AddMailToQueue("a", "b", "c", 2, "d");
```

- X: AddMailToQueue
- Y: 4
- Z: 2

*The method name X may or may not be prefixed (eg this.AddMailToQueue).*

I came up with the following: `.*AddMailToQueue\(.+2.*\);` but this regex does not take into account the position of the argument and will also return matches where Z = 20, 21, etc.

My reasoning is that the comma separating the arguments can probably be used to pinpoint argument Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want a .NET solution, but here is a regex that works in Java, then maybe you can convert it.

```
AddMailToQueue\s*\(([^,]+,){3}\s*2\s*[,)]
```

Things get easier if you start counting your parameters from zero. You would put the parameter's index **Y** where you see `3` and the paramater's value **Z** where you see `2`.

[See it working](http://regex101.com/r/hX2rO9/3)

Comment: It works perfectly, no changes required! Also, removing the initial .* (just before the method name) made the search much faster!